# What is the use of other modes in AVAudioSession, when default mode is compatible for all categories?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession

```
// Access the shared, singleton audio session instance
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    // Configure the audio session for movie playback
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback,
                            mode: AVAudioSessionModeMoviePlayback,
                            options: [])
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to set the audio session category and mode: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Unable to understand the use of modes in audio sessions.

[modes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qiwp2.png)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode. Each mode's purpose is explained, with additional details on the linked pages.

Comment: But the default mode is capable of handling all categories, then why other modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other modes are optimized for specific usages. "Compatible" is not the same as "best." For example, when using the [video chat mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/mode/1616590-videochat):

> the device’s tonal equalization is optimized for voice and the set of allowable audio routes is reduced to only those appropriate for video chat.

Comment: Okay got it, thnx ^^